# Terraform subnet call into virtual network gateway

Tags: terraform

How we can call subnet into Virtual network gateway?

**Subnet**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  name                = "vNetVPN-Dev"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = ["10.1.16.0/23", "10.2.0.0/16", "172.16.100.0/24"]

  subnet {
    name           = "snet-vpg-dev"
    address_prefix = "10.2.1.0/24"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = var.tag_dev
  }
}
```

**Virtual network gateway**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "virtual_network_gateway" {
  name                = "vgw-vgp-dev"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "Basic"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.name
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    subnet_id                     = **here I wan to call my subnet which is defined in the code above**
  }

}
```

so as you can see that there are 2 code blocks, 1 is subnet and the other is virtual network gateway.

I want to refer subnet (**snet-vpg-dev**) into virtual network gateway as a value of parameter called **subnet_id**

Comment: I think `subnet_id = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet.id` should work.

Comment: I am getting error **Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?**

Comment: And if you were to output just `azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet` as a terraform output and add that to the question? I might be able to give a better answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the Id of the subnet, you can take the subnet exported attribute of the vnet, convert it to a list and take the first element, like this

```
ip_configuration {
    name                          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.name
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    subnet_id                     = tolist(azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet)[0].id
}
```

Another solution is to use the **azurerm_subnet** resource rather than the inline subnet blocks.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet

You can directly retrieve the id of the subnet since it has a dedicated resource

The template would be something like

**Subnet**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  name                = "vNetVPN-Dev"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = ["10.1.16.0/23", "10.2.0.0/16", "172.16.100.0/24"]

  tags = {
    environment = var.tag_dev
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "vNetVPN-Dev"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.2.1.0/24"]
}
```

**Virtual network gateway**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "virtual_network_gateway" {
  name                = "vgw-vgp-dev"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  type     = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"

  active_active = false
  enable_bgp    = false
  sku           = "Basic"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.name
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip_address.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  }
}
```