# How can I reference azurerm_subnet which in not declared in the root module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a virtual network with 2 subnets

**Virtual network**: vNetVPN-Dev

**Subnet**: snet-vgp-dev

**Subnet**: snet-internal-vm

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  name                = "vNetVPN-Dev"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = ["10.1.16.0/23", "10.2.0.0/16", "172.16.100.0/24"]

  subnet {
    name           = "snet-vgp-dev"
    address_prefix = "10.2.1.0/24"
  }

  # =================== Virtual network for vm
  subnet {
    name            = "snet-internal-vm"
    address_prefix = "10.2.10.0/24"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = var.tag_dev
  }
}
```

and now I want to reference **snet-internal-vm** in this block of code (below)

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                = "internal-nic-vm"
  location            = var.resource_group_location_north_europe
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal-vm"
    subnet_id                     = **here_I_want_to_reference**
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

Comment: And where is `snet-internal-vm` defined? Or even, where is network interface resource defined relative to the virtual network resource?

Comment: **azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet.*.id[1]** or  **tolist(azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet)[1].id** will give the subnet Id you need. Same question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057681/terraform-subnet-call-into-virtual-network-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create NIC creation with **Subnet** reference:**

**Terraform Code**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
 resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
    name  = "vNetVPN-Dev"
    location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    address_space  = ["10.1.16.0/23", "10.2.0.0/16", "172.16.100.0/24"]
    subnet {
    name  = "snet-vgp-dev"
    address_prefix = "10.2.1.0/24"
    
    }
    subnet {
    name  = "snet-internal-vm"
    address_prefix = "10.2.10.0/24"
    }
    }
    
    #-----NIC Creation-----------
    
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
    name  = "internal-nic-vm"
    location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    ip_configuration {
    name  = "internal-vm"
    subnet_id  = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network.subnet.*.id[1]
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    }
    }
```

**Terraform Apply.**

[image]

As mentioned by @**sylvainmtz** , I could get subnet referred successfully while creating **NIC**.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. This is how I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I can only assume you should be using data blocks to do this. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet